# JQuery Adds Class but no visual change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webforms, devexpress

My JQuery code adds class to the html but I'm not seeing any visual change, does anyone know why? I'm using DevExpress, Webforms.

```
.BoldRed {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}

function onTextBoxInit(s, e) {
    if (s.GetText().indexOf('1') > -1)
        $(s.GetInputElement()).addClass("BoldRed");
    else
        $(s.GetInputElement()).removeClass("BoldRed");
}
```

The actual output:

```
<input class="dxeEditArea_DevEx dxeEditAreaSys BoldRed" name="ctl00$ctl00$ASPxSplitter1$Content$ContentSplitter$MainContent$ASPxCallbackPanel1$ASPxFormLayout3$ASPxFormLayout3_E1" value="106971" id="ASPxFormLayout3_E1_I" onchange="aspxEValueChanged('ASPxFormLayout3_E1')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('ASPxFormLayout3_E1')" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('ASPxFormLayout3_E1')" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: rgb(192, 224, 206);font-weight: bold;      color:red;">
```

Comment: the `style` attribute overrides anything in the css file- that button already has `font-weight` and `color` specified, so the CSS won't be able to change it unless you go the terrible route (not noted here because I'm pretty sure your problem is all buttons have it in the `style` rather than just the one with the class you're trying to style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline style has higher priority than external css. Your class applies, but its rules are ovewritten. now you have two possibilies: removing inline style (preferred) of adding !important at the end of the rules you want with higher priority.

Comment: Considering his class applies the same style as the inline, which is likely what his problem is, `!important` won't save him here. Though agreed on not using it. I tend to downvote solutions based around it on principle haha

Comment: It's daylight savings time... I lost an hour of sleep, my apologies. `!important` worked. Takes a big sip of coffee.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe adding `!important` should be the go-to solution unless is absolutely necessary, I would do the following:

```
document.querySelector('.BoldRed').style = '';
```

The above removes the inline styling from the element, your `addClass` styles won't be overriden by the inline styling.

```
.BoldRed {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
}

function onTextBoxInit(s, e) {
    if (s.GetText().indexOf('1') > -1)
        document.querySelector('.BoldRed').style = '';
        $(s.GetInputElement()).addClass("BoldRed");
    else
        $(s.GetInputElement()).removeClass("BoldRed");
}
```

NOTE: your inline style and your CSS style are the same, I assume this is a mistake?

EDIT - you'll might have to change the queryselector above to this:

```
document.querySelector('.dxeEditAreaSys').style = '';
```

In example:

```
function onTextBoxInit(s, e) {
        if (s.GetText().indexOf('1') > -1)
            document.querySelector('.dxeEditAreaSys').style = '';
            $(s.GetInputElement()).addClass("BoldRed");
        else
            $(s.GetInputElement()).removeClass("BoldRed");
    }
```

Comment: This is giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'style' of null` error highlighting the `style = '';`

Comment: Here's a working fiddle using this technique: [https://jsfiddle.net/97eoknzh/](https://jsfiddle.net/97eoknzh/). Might be to do with the way it is within the if statement, it will definitely work though - I can't see the exact reason without seeing your full code.

Comment: @sojim2, see revised EDIT

Comment: I tried, but still not working... this is most likely a devexpress quirk. I'll have to get in touch with them about this problem. It doesn't give any error but there's no visual change. add `!important` worked however.